# When scrolling the custom list view then automatically some row are clicked . Might me logic should write correctly

Tags: android

When I use relative layout then it works fine but not working properly when I used adapter :-

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View clickedView, int position, long arg3) {
                    //TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int clickedRowID = -1;  


                if (clickedRowID != -1 && clickedRowID != position) {


            if (clickedView != null) {

                            holder.add_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                    System.err.println("clickedView null");
                }
            }
            if ((clickedRowID != position)) {
            // position=position-1;

            final Get_Preference_model item = (Get_Preference_model) parent
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);



            holder.add_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        clickedRowID = position;

                    } else if (clickedRowID == position) {


                        holder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        clickedRowID = -1;
                        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
        int clickedRowID = -1;  

        if (clickedRowID != -1 ...
```

is like a dead code, you set -1 and checks if there is NOT -1 so this will never fire. And this:

```
if ((clickedRowID != position))
```

will never fire either because position will never be -1.